# where can i find (edit) the jobs that are going to run in cron.php of drupal?

Tags: drupal, cron

How can i edit the list of jobs that are going to run at running time of /DocRoot/cron.php in drupal??
in other words, where can i edit the list of drupal jobs that return from **drupal_cron_run**?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no UI for this on the Drupal core. Drupal cron will run all the [`hook_cron()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) implementations in the enabled modules. You can get all cron implementation on a Drupal site using [`module_implements('cron')`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_implements).

The [SuperCron](http://drupal.org/project/supercron) or [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) modules can be used for more fine-grained control of the cron.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard or read that an UI for it exists. My first intention on your question was:

```
konnertz@auedv20:/var/www/vhosts/drupal-6.20$ grep hook_cron * -rn
includes/common.inc:2715:  // Try to allocate enough time to run all the hook_cron implementations.
modules/node/node.module:119: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/ping/ping.module:23: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/aggregator/aggregator.module:285: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/openid/openid.module:669: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/trigger/trigger.module:141: *   because some hooks (e.g., hook_cron()) do not have operations.
modules/trigger/trigger.module:314: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/search/search.module:261: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/dblog/dblog.module:99: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/system/system.module:1274: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/filter/filter.module:161: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/statistics/statistics.module:177: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/update/update.module:294: * Implementation of hook_cron().
modules/poll/poll.module:155: * Implementation of hook_cron().
```

This is  a fresh installation. Otherwise there would be more in sites/all/modules.

To not run some jobs one could either comment out the hook_cron in the modules or in 
includes/common.php replace line 2747

```
     module_invoke_all('cron');
```

with the concrete invoke methods, adhoc i am not sure how to do that. 
This is all for drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution**: As of Jan, 2012 the below mentioned module is abandoned due to a security issue the maintainer never fixed. See SA-2012-006 for details.

From the Drupal project page:

Maintenance status: Unsupported 
Development status: No further development

---

Here you go http://drupal.org/project/supercron

I guess this fits your need. Just found it.

> SuperCron is a complete replacement
>   for Drupal's built-in Cron
>   functionality. It allows you to:
>
> See the list of all Cron hooks found
>   in the enabled modules Change the
>   order in which cron hooks are called
>   Disable certain hooks 
>   (...)